# Как каждые 10 часов очищать файл text.txt

Tags: php

В файле text.txt вписываются данные, 
Как его очищать каждые 10 часов помогите ребятки (.
Дайте примкр кода

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996860/php-clear-content-in-txt-file-every-24-hours

Comment: формально, чтобы очистить файл сам пхп то и не нужен, и даже излишен

Comment: А как это сделать без PHP . ребятки помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: Который раз дубликат?

Comment: Таки нарисовать задание в кроне или в планировщике

Comment: @Visman второй минимум

Comment: Я не мог получить нормальный совет , все только и говорят иди туда делай то,... А что именно никто не говорит хотябы пример дали чтоли... новичков не ппиветствют кажется, я за помощью пришел ребят,

Comment: @Encode_VI, советы вы нормальные уже получали. Вы хотите не совет, а точный ответ, чтобы самому ни о чем не думать и не изучать!!!

Comment: @Encode_VI ну давай так. ты сформулируй конкретно что тебе нужно. в чем именно возникли трудности. у тебя есть скрипт и не знаешь как запустить его каждый интервал времени? или у тебя нет скрипта и ты не знаешь что в нем должно быть или еще что? что у тебя в файле? зачем очищать его? .... так у тебя не описано ничего. абстрактный непонятный текст.

Comment: Сейчас твой вопрос сводится тупо к запуску скрипта каждые 10 часов, и ответ на этот самый вопрос был в прошлый раз, но ты почему-то проигнорил

Answer (score 0):

Нужен мини `php` скрипт `cleartxt.php`, со следующим содержанием:

```
file_put_contents("path/filename.txt", "");
```

где `path/filename.txt` - полный путь к файлу.

И выполнение данного скрипта нужно поставить на `cron`

```
0 */10 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/cleartxt.php
```

где `/path/cleartxt.php` полный путь до скрипта `cleartxt.php`

upd: чтобы добавить запись в `cron`,в консоли сервера выполните `crontab -e` и в редакторе добавьте запись

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, вот сейчас понял, я пргсто с крон задачами не знаком ещё

Comment: объясните, зачем здесь использовать пхп вообще? `> file.txt` - все что требуется.

Comment: @teran, вопрос с меткой `php`, возможно будут происходить какие-то доп манипуляции

Comment: В файле messages.txt будут записываться сообщения из чата , поэтому нужно очищать файл каждые 10 часов, чтобы небыло мусора много, а то через месяц будет сайт зависать

Comment: если не нужен `php`, как писал @teran, повесьте задачу на крон без использования `php` скрипта: `0   */10    *    *    *    > path/filename.txt`